# How to Interpret WMAP's statement they have "nailed down the curvature of space to within 0.4% of "flat" Euclidean"”

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I find myself slightly frustrated when I'm reading a [NASA page](https://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/) and they claim they have

> “nailed down the curvature of space to within 0.4% of "flat"
>   Euclidean”

0.4% of what? Mathematically this statement is un-useful as you can extract no information out of it.

This is equivalent to saying the neutrino mass is measured within 0.4% to be zero, an equally meaningless statement.

What researchers DO report are upper and lower bounds on Neutrino (and other particle) masses such as the title of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04320):

> “On the improvement of cosmological neutrino mass bounds”

which actually tells you something you can quickly jump to a table and absorb the information from it.

In the same spirit the spatial curvature of our universe should be described by a statment like (for a made up example):

“

> Our analysis concludes that the spatial radius of curvature of our
>   universe $R$ is bounded by:$$\frac{1}{\mid R\mid}\leq9\cdot10^{-46}m^{-1}\pm error$$

How can I get this data from their study?

(If I remember right R here should correspond to spatial components of the Ricci tensor (at cosmological scales anyway)).

Comment: Most particle physicists I talk to don't avoid saying the photon mass is zero, and just say it is zero without any issue

Comment: @Triatticus    Fair enough, maybe I'll scrub that last part, but even on tables of particle masses a bound is usually given.

Comment: @Triatticus    Just for fun you might want to read about Wheeler's "geons" which (although an exotic concept) appear to impart the classical EM field  with mass.

Comment: @Triatticus Except when they want to eliminate the infrared catastrophe !

Comment: @my2cts Even then It's stated as an unphysical mass, the same can be done with dimensional regularization or a cut-off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is not meaningless. The curvature parameter, $\Omega_k$, used in cosmology is a dimensionless parameter. So the statement that it is flat to within 0.4% means that the parameter has been measured to be between -0.004 and +0.004. It is a dimensionless number so the number has meaning on its own and does not need an “of what” qualifier.

The writers of the press release just (reasonably) decided that a message to the public saying “within 0.4% of flat” would be more generally understandable than “$\Omega_k = -0.0027 ^{+0.0039}_{-0.0038}$”

See here for the actual paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5226

Comment: +1 I totally forgot it was a dimensionless ratio! SIlly me (sheepish grin) Just one thing, I believe that $\Omega=1$ is flat. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Yes $\Omega=1$ is flat but the “0.4% of flat” comment refers specifically to $\Omega_k$ for which flat is 0. I added a link to the original paper and the correct value of the finding.

Answer (score 2):

Since Dale Got me going on the right track I'm going to go ahead and Accept his answer I just wanted to Add something to it and figured another answer would suffice for this.
 According to [This Caltech Webpage](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Peacock/Peacock3_2.html)  We can write the scale factor R for a standard FLRW universe as:

$$R_{0}=\frac{c}{H_{0}}[(\Omega-1)/k]^{-1/2}$$

Where $c/H_0$ is the hubble length, Omega is as Dale described above and k is either plus or minus 1 for a closed or open universe respectively. This is really just a rearrangement of the Friedmann equation.

In the case of $\Omega=1\pm0.004$ and $H_{0}\approx1.3\cdot10^{26}m$ (or about 14 billion light years) One obtains:

$$\mid R_{0}\mid\geq2\cdot10^{27}m$$

Corresponding to a radius of curvature of more than 200 Billion Light Years!!

Rather than being being flat the universe could just be Really Really big. There's no reason to suppose that it isn't since It is after all, the universe we are talking about.

I feel I should note that for positive curvature we have a finite volume for the universe, whereas for negative or zero curvature one gets infinite universes (or some boundary? I'm not going to touch that!) 
I get that observations of accelerating expansion all but rule out a closed universe, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: “Rather than being being flat the universe could just be Really Really big.” Yes, exactly correct. The data is consistent with three possibilities. Either it is flat or negatively curved (both of which imply an infinite universe) or it could be positively curved. If it is positively curved then it would be closed, but very large such that the radius of curvature is so large that we cannot yet confidentially detect it.

Comment: That should be “confidently” not “confidentially”